# how to add string to a dataframe

Tags: string, dataframe, concatenation

I have a random dataframe generated:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(15, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

I want all values in Column "A" to start with A. I have tried the below code:

```
print('A' + df['A'])
```

this seems to be erroring out :

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matchin types dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11')
```

What is the right way to do this? Or alternately what is the rest way to generate a random dataframe stating with a particular letter string for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'A' + str(x)))
```

also check the official doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: can I have a combination of AB used i.e. sometimes use A and sometimes use B ?

Comment: please clarify what exactly you want, from your description it is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: I wanted some of the data to start with A and some with B. I achieved that by putting the values in and using your method. `df2['A'] = df2['A'].apply(lambda x: random.choice(list) + str(x))`